How to visualize the compound trigonometric function like sin(tan(x)) and find this limit?
This question comes out from the book Visual Differential geometry and Forms by Needham, the 4th exercise for Prologue and Act I, where we need to find the limit of
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin\tan x - \tan \sin x}{\sin^{-1} \tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1} \sin^{-1}x} 
$$
Using the power series expansion at $x=0$, I have already found that this limit is 1.
But it is more interesting that Needham suggests that the readers solving this problem by using the Newtonian geometrical reasoning, which is where I am stuck. I have thought about it for a few weeks, but finding nothing good enough to visualize the compound trigonometric function like $\sin\tan x$ or $\sin^{-1}\tan^{-1} x$. But then how should I find this limit by reasoning geometrically?
The screenshot of this exercise in the book Visual Differential geometry and Forms

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.
